# Filtering index page by one search box and two dropdown boxes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, filter, simple-form

I'm trying to filter the results of an index page given the content of a search box and whatever is selected on 2 other dropdowns.

I'm using simple_form and I already got the search BOX to work and filter the results with one of the params:

My view:

```
<%= form_tag(entitys_path, method: :get) do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :name_filter, params[:name_filter] %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Search' , name: nil %>
<% end %>
```

My index method:

```
def index
    @entitys = if params[:name_filter]
        Entity.joins(:user).where('LOWER(users.name) LIKE?', "%# 
        {params[:name_filter]}%".downcase).paginate(page: 
        params[:page], per_page: 8)
    else            
        @entitys = Entity.all.paginate(page: params[:page], 
        per_page: 8)
    end
end
```

I can't figure out how to make 2 more dropdowns and apply those to the index method filtering.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll want to look into `select_tag`, which acts like `text_field_tag` (directly adding it's value to `params`.

Comment: @AJFaraday Thank you for your reply. I'm looking at the select tag syntax and I don't quite understand how to adapt it to my case. For some context, I am listing entities and I need a dropdown to list entities by location and another dropdown for activity. I already have 2 def in my application helper called get_all_locations and get_all_activities , how would I fill up said boxes with those methods? Really sorry, I'm very new to rails .

Comment: Not a problem, It takes time to learn. I'd use this method to generate your options https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View:

```
<%= form_tag(entitys_path, method: :get) do %>
          <%= text_field_tag :name_filter, params[:name_filter] %>
          <%= select_tag :location_filter, options_for_select(get_city_list) %>
           <%= select_tag :activity_filter, options_for_select(get_professional_activity_list) %>
          <%= submit_tag 'Procurar' , name: nil %>
        <% end %>
```

Controller index method:

```
def index
        if params[:name_filter].present? || params[:activity_filter].present? || params[:location_filter].present?
            @entitys = Entity.joins(:user).where('LOWER(users.name) LIKE?', "%#{params[:name_filter]}%".downcase).where('LOWER(entities.location) LIKE?', "%#{params[:location_filter]}%".downcase).where('LOWER(entities.professional_activity) LIKE?', "%#{params[:activity_filter]}%".downcase).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 8)
        else    
            @entitys = Entity.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 8)
        end
    end
enter code here
```

This worked for what I needed (or so it seems)

Answer (score 0):

From a comment, it looks like the question is about how to populate select tags. Here's the methods needed

- [select_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag)
- [options_from_collection_for_select](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select)

So they'll probably look like this:

```
<%= select_tag(
  'location',
  options_from_collection_for_select(
    get_all_locations,
    'name', # The method called to generate the value passed up to the controller
    'name'  # The value displayed to users
  )
) %>
```

This will populate `params[:location]` when the form is submitted.

Comment: Thanks once again, I was indeed trying to figure out how to work that out, but what would the 3rd and 4th arguments be exactly? What you labeled as 'name' , that is. I don't know what my "The method called to generate the value passed up to the controller" is supposed to be, maybe I'm missing something very obvious

Comment: Okay, so the first argument is a collection (usually an Array, but it can be an ActiveRecord::Relation). It will call two methods on each member of the collection, one to decide what to show users in that select, and one to decide what to pass up to the controller when it's submitted. In my example I've set both to 'name'. So it will call `location.name` to decide what to show to the user, and it will pass `location.name` to the controller as `params[:location]`

Comment: Thank you, I managed to adapt and figure out a way that works with your guidance! 
  <%= select_tag :location_filter, options_for_select(get_city_list) %>
This worked for me while in my controller I have:
if params[:name_filter].present? || params[:activity_filter].present? || params[:location_filter].present? 
Followed by the where clauses.

Comment: Posted as an answer to my own post, also new to stackoverflow posting. Thanks once again AJ!